# Use both ormlite and robojuice in a Android Activity

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I would like to use both [robojuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice) & [ormlite](http://ormlite.com/).

If I want to use ormlite my Activity have to extend OrmLiteBaseActivity and for robojuice it should extend RoboActivity.

What is the best practice to mix them ?

Comment: Too bad java doesn't have multiple inheritance..

Comment: well I know .. maybe there is a builtin solution. I can for example extends a OrmLiteRoboJuice class. In this class I extend RoboActivity and I will copy the code of OrmLiteBaseActivity but it's ugly ..